# Value in mask is not correct Angular

Tags: angular, mask

I have the following library
https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html

and I created this directive

[image]

My TS

```
initForm() {
     this.form = this.fb.group({
           item_number: [this.service.lpu.item_number, Validators.required],
           material: [this.service.lpu.material, Validators.required],
           description: [this.service.lpu.description, Validators.required],
           unit: [this.service.lpu.unit, Validators.required],
           net_value: ['', Validators.required],
           gross_amount: ['', Validators.required],
           lpu_type: [this.service.lpu.lpu_type, Validators.required],
     });
}
```

and my view

```
<div fxFlex="35" fxFill fxLayoutAlign="start center">
       <mat-form-field>
           <mat-label>Valor Bruto</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="gross_amount" money>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div fxFlex></div>
        <div fxFlex="35" fxFill fxLayoutAlign="start center">
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Valor Líquido</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="net_value" money>
            </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

in console I have this result
[image]

I dont know why the result comes like this "1,550" and "55,000"
I need that the resul to come linke this "15,00" and "550,00"
any ideia ?

Comment: Can you please provide what the input value was before being parsed by the mask and what it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mask is not working properly. The example in the library repository could be better, it doens't show the expected result of this specific mask.

```js
mask("#.##0,00", {reverse: true}); // maybe wrong?!
```

Did you try his first money mask example?

```js
mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
```

I'd recommend trying different patterns at the mask definition, since the problem is probably there